# Is it possible to gather use history information from a WLAN modem?

Tags: wireless-networking

I suspect that my WLAN was hacked, i.e. that someone has connected to the internet through it.

My modem is a Speedport W 502V and I would like to know if the modem keeps a log of past connections that I can search for possible intruders in the last weeks or months.
Is such information kept after a reset (I had to reset the modem because I had forgotten the password and I wanted to disable the WLAN).

Or does the modem only register currently open connections?

Comment: **If** it was hacked then whoever did that could have deleted log files. (Assuming they are kept at all).

Comment: @Hennes: My point is whether the modem does have log files and where they are kept.

Comment: For a modern GNU/Linux install they would be kept in /var/log. Many routers use a trimmed down version of GNU/Linux. Not all though, and I do not know what the Speedport W 502V uses. And even if it used G/L it might be turned off to save disk space, which is rather scarce in modems. -- Regardless, I meant the first comment as a "If you do have logs and you do not find anything, then that does not mean that you are safe. Merely that the modem has not been hack **or** that the hacker was not incompetent".

Comment: @Hennes: I understand. The modem only has a web-based interface and I do not have the faintest idea how to connect to it so that I can look at the log files. I am going to look if I can find some documentation.